# Boostrap Navbar-Toggler Code from the documentation is stuck ON and won't toggle off

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, toggle, navbar

I am looking to have a navbar toggler so it still looks okay for mobile.

Here is the link to the bootstrap documentation that I'm referring to.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Take for example their code here:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

When I am on their site and run the inspect, everything runs perfectly fine.
When I run the code on my site, the dropdown menu is default on and cannot be turned off. Any help would be well appreciated.

I'm kind of an absolute mess with the libraries so I will include that as well, there could be some dependency issues that I am not understanding.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo/icon_logo.png') }}">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/2bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="static/css/main.css"> 
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Mansura</title>
</head>
```

*stuff in the body below

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/bootstrap-js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

This mess is really me trying to throw s*** at the wall and see if I can get anything to make it work, seems to not have helped.

Thanks

Comment: For starters, notice how you are linking to the documentation for Bootstrap v4 - but the JavaScript resources you are embedding, are for v3.x.y ...?

Comment: @CBroe there is a 3.x.x at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You are using the script 2 times remove this script from the header and just keep it body below.

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```